# Title: Missing condition for password validation in Symfony controller

Tags: symfony, symfony5.4

I'm working on a Symfony application where I have a controller method for updating the user's password. However, I seem to have made an error in the code, and I'm having trouble figuring out the issue.

In my userPasswordEdit method, I'm using a Symfony form to handle the password update. The method checks if the form is submitted and valid, and then it proceeds to update the user's password. However, I realize that I forgot to include a condition for password validation, which means the update happens regardless of whether the repeated password matches the original password.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    Instructeur + leerling controller   
    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#[Route('/profile/password', name: 'edit_password')]
public function userPasswordEdit(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher): Response
{
    // Code to retrieve the user and handle the form submission

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // Code to hash and update the password

        // Intentional error: Missing condition for password validation

        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();

        // Code to add a flash message and redirect
    }
}

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
#[Route('/profile/edit', name: 'edit_profile')]
    public function userProfileEdit(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher): Response
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $form = $this->createForm(EditProfileType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $user->setName($form->get('name')->getData());
            $user->setEmail($form->get('email')->getData());
            $user->setTel($form->get('tel')->getData());

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Profiel is succesvol aangepast!');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_profile');
        }
        
        return $this->render('user/edit_profile.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user, 'profile_form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }           
        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
            
    #[Route('/menu/delete/{id}', name: 'delete_item')]
    public function delete_item($id, MenuRepository $menuRepository, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $menu_item = $menuRepository->find($id);

        $entityManager->remove($menu_item);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', $menu_item->getName() .' is succesvol verwijderd van het menu!');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_menu');        
        
        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TWIG:

<td><a href="{{ path('admin_order', {id: order.id}) }}"> Order number: {{ order.id }}</a></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missing condition for password validation. To add the missing condition for password validation in your `userPasswordEdit` method, you need to compare the repeated password with the original password before updating it.

Here's how you can modify your code to include the validation check:

Instructeur + leerling controller

```
#[Route('/profile/password', name: 'edit_password')]
public function userPasswordEdit(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher): Response
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $form = $this->createForm(EditPasswordType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $plainPassword = $form->get('password')->getData();
        $repeatPlainPassword = $form->get('repeatPassword')->getData();

        if ($repeatPlainPassword === $plainPassword){
            $hashedPassword = $passwordHasher->hashPassword($user, $plainPassword);
            $user->setPassword($hashedPassword);

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Wachtwoord is succesvol gewijzigd!');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_profile');
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Ingevoerde wachtwoorden komen niet overeen!')</script>";
        }
    }


#[Route('/profile/edit', name: 'edit_profile')]
    public function userProfileEdit(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher): Response
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $form = $this->createForm(EditProfileType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $user->setName($form->get('name')->getData());
            $user->setEmail($form->get('email')->getData());
            $user->setTel($form->get('tel')->getData());

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Profiel is succesvol aangepast!');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_profile');
        }
        
        return $this->render('user/edit_profile.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user, 'profile_form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }           
        
    #[Route('/menu/delete/{id}', name: 'delete_item')]
    public function delete_item($id, MenuRepository $menuRepository, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $menu_item = $menuRepository->find($id);

        $entityManager->remove($menu_item);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', $menu_item->getName() .' is succesvol verwijderd van het menu!');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_menu');
```

TWIG:

```
<td><a href="{{ path('admin_order', {id: order.id}) }}"> Order number{{ order.id }}</a></td>
```